# find last char in std::string ERROR: Expression: string subscript out of range

Tags: c++

So, this returns an error on execution, no errors shown in the debugger.

Debug assertion failed!

Expression: String subscript out of range.

For information on how your program can couse an assertion failure, see the visual c++ documentation on asserts.

```
int main()
{
// declaring variables
string input = "";
int firstChar;

// process:
cout << "Please enter a valid sentence (with spaces):\n>";
getline(cin, input);

cout << "first char is " + input[0] << endl << endl;
firstChar = input.length();
cout << "last char is " + input[firstChar];

// stop and return success
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input[firstChar]` is attempting to access the byte one-pass the end of the character array `input` because arrays are indexed by `[0, length)`.

The last character is actually `input[firstChar - 1]`.

Just a little tip, use the stream insertion operator `<<` instead of `+` because the latter yeilds a temporary `std::string` object.

Comment: Thank you, your answer made more sense to me, than the one below, thanks

Answer (score 5):

C++ strings of length `length` are indexed from `0` to `length - 1`.

Comment: The string might even be 0 length, you should not assume that ```input[0]``` is valid.

Comment: In that case indexing would go from 0 to -1 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should test that in your `input` is a valid content before using it.Something like `if(length(input)>0)...`.The user might not give the wanted data even if you typed what you need  between ()  and validations are needed